# Potential surface water based on slope degrees - QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, overlay

I have two sets of raster data that I would like to combine but under a condition. I have derived a slope raster from my DEM, and I have already classified it based on slope values in my AOI (degrees) (Fig 1.). I have also exported a raster layer of potential surface water pixels from my SAR satellite image based on backscatter values from the Sentinel Toolbox (Fig 3.).

I want to overlay the two layers onto each other but to avoid errors, I want to remove or set value to NaN of surface water present in high steepness areas. The goal of my research is to find surface water from a flooding event that has occurred last year.

Unfortunately my image is a single polarised image with shadows highly prominent in an urbanised area I'm looking at. To mitigate this I want to add a LiDAR dataset to it (Slope).

Anyone got any ideas that could help me?

[image: Reclassified Slope Data]

[image: Slope Values (Degrees)]

[image: Surface Water Pixels]